# What will be the Domain name in Facebook or Twitter Page if Social Login is done from Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, facebook-login

I'm trying to create a social login Google Chrome Extension But have no idea of what should be the domain name of redirect URL in doing so.

Is there any social login service I can use for creating Facebook and Twitter Login In Chrome-Extension ?